# What is the importance of PropTypes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm still learning React and can't grasp the importance of `PropTypes`. Can anyone give their thoughts what are the benefits of defining your `PropTypes`? I've read the discussion about this on the React documentation but I can't grasp the advantages of keeping `PropTypes` aside from seeing console error/warnings when types doesn't match. It says on the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html)

> When designing interfaces, break down the common design elements
>   (buttons, form fields, layout components, etc.) into reusable
>   components with well-defined interfaces. **That way, the next time you
>   need to build some UI, you can write much less code.** This means faster
>   development time, fewer bugs, and fewer bytes down the wire.

So aside from the benefits I have a few other questions:

1. When defining `PropTypes` you are definitely writing more code which contradicts that statement in bold.
2. Another question is, are `PropTypes` only applicable to child components since parent components don't usually have props?
3. If so, how do we check the types of the states of the parent components, is there a `StateTypes` so to speak?

Comment: *"how do we check the types of the states of the parent components"* It doesn't make sense to validate state since only the component itself can change its state.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

React revolves around the concept of components. A whole webpage should be broken down into components and each components will interact with each other through `props`.

So, these are all the advantages of using `PropTypes`

- Validate the prop passed to a child and warn the developer when a wrong props is passed, which may break your app.
- As a team, when a member of the team creates a component, you won't know what to do with that unless you see the `PropTypes`

`PropTypes` is not compulsory.

**[EDIT] Answers for the questions in order**

1. Yes, you'll be writing extra code. But, if you need to validate your `props`, which is extra code, you don't need to do it by yourself. Validations will be taken care by `React` itself.
2. Not Exactly, there's a difference between `Parent` and `Root` component. `Parent` component can be a child of another `Parent` which can be a child of another. So, call it as `Root` component which will be at the top of the UI tree. With this definition, you can say, `PropType` is only applicable to `Parent` and `Child`, not `Root` component.
3. You don't need to check the `stateType` because `state` is with in a component's scope. But, `props` are passed from a component to another. So, it doesn't make sense to validate `state` of a component as it is not shared across components. Even if it is shared, that can be only done through `props`.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you for answering the benefits. Do you have any insights about my additional questions?

Comment: @JohnnyQ Added the answers. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Pranesh Ravi what if the props are coming from the redux store,do we still need to define proptypes?

Comment: @JohnAnisere propTypes are purely for debugging purpose. It's good to add them.

Answer (score 1):

1. `PropTypes` let you validate your props, which otherwise is not possible, since JavaScript is loosely typed language.
2. You can have `props` wherever you need them, including parents. Or do not have them at all. Often `props` are the only way to pass some values or callbacks from parents to children and grandchildren (in fact it is recommended way).
3. There's no StateTypes.

Comment: Thank you for your message. So how do we check the types of the initial states initialized by the parent/main components?